# Native voids from the java runtime can be accessed, just like that?

Tags: java

So, I am fiddling around for another answer and I noticed these two methods([bytesToFloats](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java#L2005) and [bytesToDoubles](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java#L2013)) in ObjectInputStream.java.

```
/**
 * Converts specified span of bytes into float values.
 */
// REMIND: remove once hotspot inlines Float.intBitsToFloat
private static native void bytesToFloats(byte[] src, int srcpos,
                                         float[] dst, int dstpos,
                                         int nfloats);

/**
 * Converts specified span of bytes into double values.
 */
// REMIND: remove once hotspot inlines Double.longBitsToDouble
private static native void bytesToDoubles(byte[] src, int srcpos,
                                          double[] dst, int dstpos,
                                          int ndoubles);
```

I was dismayed at first, because they are private, native and I thought it's end of the line in my experiments. However, I did an experiment before giving up and just copied these method definitions over in my own class I was experimenting with and it worked.

So my question is: Why does it work? Why are the native methods accessible like this from "anywhere" I would have expected some guards or gateposts when accessing native methods.

To clarify my question further: I'm curious why the native methods of java.io can be accessed from anywhere, without any pointer what's exactly accessed. it kinda feels like a weird superglobal to me.

Comment: Did the class you copied them to have the same fully-qualified name?

Comment: @TavianBarnes No. Not in the slightest. https://ideone.com/OTn2IG

Comment: What does "it worked" mean?  That it compiled? Or that you actually called those methods in your class successfully?  Consider posting a minimal but complete example.

Comment: @Tschallacka I don't see where you're actually calling those methods.  You won't get an error unless you call them.

Comment: https://ideone.com/AFYjNM This cannot find the native method.

Comment: @matt ah, so it's a runtime error if it doesn't exist. It'll compile fine then, but throw an error when it's called. I still wonder why it can compile though. I would imagine the compiler would throw a check against what's available? or is it always  good faith assumption that the running machine will provide something? Can you turn this into an answer?

Comment: @Tschallacka The compiler can't check it because native libraries are loaded at runtime with `System.loadLibrary()`

Comment: @TavianBarnes Ah, I learned something new then about native libraries. Granted, it's been 15 years since I actively worked with them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler 'assumes' that you have provided the native lib.

```
class Ideone
{
    private static native void bytesToDoubles(byte[] src, int srcpos,
                                          double[] dst, int dstpos,
                                          int ndoubles);
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        byte[] bytes = { 1, 2, 3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        double[] dst = new double[1];
        bytesToDoubles(bytes, 0, dst, 0, 1);
        System.out.println(dst[0]);
    }
}
```

With this answer we can see that when we run the program there will not be a native lib.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  >Ideone.bytesToDoubles([BI[DII)V
>     at Ideone.bytesToDoubles(Native Method)
>     at Ideone.main(Main.java:17)

So to access another classes native lib, you would need to use the fully qualified classname. Hence it would be afforded the 'protection' that private is offering.